# Spring map one url to another without a redirect

Tags: java, spring, maven, url, spring-mvc

What's the best way in a `spring` web application to allow the root url `/` to alias a page `index.html`?

The premise is a [`webjar`](http://www.webjars.org/) that contains all web resources, css files, javascript, web pages and an `index.html` that I want to import and display in an otherwise empty `war` project.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("webjars/gui/1.0/**");
    }
}
```

Note: The handler pattern `/**` is necessary for the resource imports in `index.html` to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of a better way I did it by the following approach

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public View welcomeUrl() {
        return new InternalResourceView("index.html");
    }
}
```

Of course there are dedicated libraries like [`urlrewrite`](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and [`rewrite`](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) that would do it, but it seems it should be possible with vanilla Spring; if nothing else then by a web interceptor or similar.